# Error when scraping Instagram list of user has stories

Tags: android, android-studio, instagram, instagram-api

about a month ago I was able to get the list of the user who has stories by using

`https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/reels_tray/`

now I get error 400 with a response:

```
{
    "message": "checkpoint_required",
    "checkpoint_url": "https://i.instagram.com/challenge/?next=/api/v1/feed/reels_tray/",
    "lock": true,
    "flow_render_type": 0,
    "status": "fail"
}
```

what should I do to fix this? Also, did we have another way to get the list of users that has stories?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering basically says that you must login to your account and verify that you're the owner before making another request. I would suggest also if you haven't done it already to add to the headers as user agent this ==> Instagram 64.0.0.14.96

Hope this helps